# Concatenation makes the training fail keras

Tags: python-2.7, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to implement the U-net CNN architecture. In this architecture, there is several concatenations in the "upsampling" part. I use keras 2.1.3, python 2.7 and tensorflow '1.4.0-rc0'

My inputs are of the shape (6,128,128) (channel first). Here is the code I've came up with

```
input_shape = (6, 128, 128)

# Create model U-net Model 
input_fields = Input(shape=input_shape)

f32 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="same")(input_fields)
f32 = Activation("relu", name="f32")(f32)

s32 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="same")(f32)
s32 = Activation("relu",name="s32")(s32) ## To concatenate 32

pool32_64 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding="same")(s32)

f64 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding="same")(pool32_64)
f64 = Activation("relu")(f64)

s64 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding="same")(f64)
s64 = Activation("relu")(s64) # To concatenate 64

pool64_128 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding="same")(s64)

f128 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding="same")(pool64_128)
f128 = Activation("relu")(f128)

s128 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding="same")(f128)
s128 = Activation("relu")(s128)
print "Last shape before Upsampling "s128.get_shape()

#### vvv Upsampling Part vvv  ####

up_128_64 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(s128)
up_128_64 = Conv2D(64, (2,2), padding="same")(up_128_64)
print "Conv2d pu_128_64 ", up_128_64.get_shape()

m64 = Concatenate(axis=0)([s64, up_128_64]) #or concatenate([s64, up_128_64], axis=0)

f64U = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding="same")(m64)
f64U = Activation("relu")(f64U)
#print "f64U.get_shape()", f64U.get_shape()


s64U = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding="same")(f64U)
s64U = Activation("relu")(s64U)

up_64_32 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(s64U)
up_64_32 = Conv2D(32, (2,2), padding="same")(up_64_32)

m32 = Concatenate(axis=0)([s32, up_64_32]) # or concatenate([s32, up_64_32], axis=0)

f32U = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="same")(m32)
f32U = Activation("relu")(f32U)
print "f32U.get_shape()", f32U.get_shape()

s32U = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="same")(f32U)
s32U = Activation("relu")(s32U)


output_field = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same")(s32U)
output_field = Activation("relu")(output_field)

print output_field.get_shape()

U_net = Model(input_fields, output_field)
U_net.summary()

U_net.compile(optimizer="RMSProp", loss="mse")#, metrics=["accuracy"])

U_net.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Concerning the U_net.summary() the output is :

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 6, 128, 128)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 128, 128) 1760        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
f32 (Activation)                (None, 32, 128, 128) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 128, 128) 9248        f32[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
s32 (Activation)                (None, 32, 128, 128) 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 64, 64)   0           s32[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 64)   18496       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 32, 32)   0           activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 32, 32)  73856       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 128, 32, 32)  0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 32, 32)  147584      activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, 128, 32, 32)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 128, 64, 64)  0           activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 64)   32832       up_sampling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           activation_2[0][0]               
                                                                 conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 64, 128, 128) 0           activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 128, 128) 8224        up_sampling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 32, 128, 128) 0           s32[0][0]                        
                                                                 conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 128, 128) 9248        concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)       (None, 32, 128, 128) 0           conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 128, 128) 9248        activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)       (None, 32, 128, 128) 0           conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 1, 128, 128)  33          activation_8[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)       (None, 1, 128, 128)  0           conv2d_13[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 421,313
Trainable params: 421,313
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The network is built and

```
X_train.shape = (576, 6, 128, 128)
y_train.shape = (576, 1, 128, 128)
```

But during the training I receive this error

```
Epoch 1/1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
........../run_CNN_tau.py in <module>()
    174 U_net.compile(optimizer="RMSProp", loss="mae")#, metrics=["accuracy"])
    175 
--> 176 U_net.fit(X_train, y_train)#, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=1)
    177 
    178 #model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(16,16), padding="same", activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1667                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1668                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1669                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1670 
   1671     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1204                         ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
   1205 
-> 1206                     outs = f(ins_batch)
   1207                     if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1208                         outs = [outs]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2473         session = get_session()
   2474         updated = session.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2475                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2476         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2477 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1118     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1119       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1120                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1121     else:
   1122       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1315     if handle is None:
   1316       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1317                            options, run_metadata)
   1318     else:
   1319       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1334         except KeyError:
   1335           pass
-> 1336       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1337 
   1338   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [96,1,128,128] vs. [32,1,128,128]
     [[Node: training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/activation_9_loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@loss/activation_9_loss/sub"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/activation_9_loss/sub_grad/Shape, training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/activation_9_loss/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]

Caused by op u'training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/activation_9_loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs', defined at:
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 119, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 355, in start
    self.shell.mainloop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 495, in mainloop
    self.interact()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 486, in interact
    self.run_cell(code, store_history=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2714, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2824, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2878, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-463-b869a174fafa>", line 1, in <module>
    get_ipython().magic(u'run run_CNN_tau.py')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2160, in magic
    return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2081, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-58>", line 2, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 188, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 742, in run
    run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 728, in run
    exit_ignore=exit_ignore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2483, in safe_execfile
    self.compile if kw['shell_futures'] else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py", line 289, in execfile
    builtin_mod.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/nsaura/Documents/Git_RANNS/ML/turbo/wk/tests/python/run_CNN_tau.py", line 176, in <module>
    U_net.fit(X_train, y_train)#, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1646, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 970, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 233, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 78, in get_gradients
    grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2512, in gradients
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 581, in gradients
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 353, in _MaybeCompile
    return grad_fn()  # Exit early
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 581, in <lambda>
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py", line 727, in _SubGrad
    rx, ry = gen_array_ops._broadcast_gradient_args(sx, sy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 532, in _broadcast_gradient_args
    "BroadcastGradientArgs", s0=s0, s1=s1, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

...which was originally created as op u'loss/activation_9_loss/sub', defined at:
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
[elided 16 identical lines from previous traceback]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py", line 289, in execfile
    builtin_mod.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/nsaura/Documents/Git_RANNS/ML/turbo/wk/tests/python/run_CNN_tau.py", line 174, in <module>
    U_net.compile(optimizer="RMSProp", loss="mae")#, metrics=["accuracy"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 827, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 426, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 18, in mean_absolute_error
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 894, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 4636, in _sub
    "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [96,1,128,128] vs. [32,1,128,128]
     [[Node: training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/activation_9_loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@loss/activation_9_loss/sub"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/activation_9_loss/sub_grad/Shape, training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/activation_9_loss/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
```

The point is, this U-net works fine if the concatenation layers are removed. Can someone explain how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the real problem, but your concatenation layers seem to have the wrong output dimensions (only 1/2 of the number of feature channels they should output)

Comment: You mean instead of concatenate_2 (Concatenate)  (None, 32, 128, 128) for example I should have had (None, 64 128, 128) since I concatenate two fields with 32 channels each ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Keras documentation, the default batch size for training is 32 samples (https://keras.io/models/model/#fit), and if I look at your architecture, it seems like you are essentially taking the input stream, splitting it, and then merging it twice (once for each Concatenate) yielding 96 samples per batch.  This might explain the error message content: "[96,1,128,128] vs. [32,1,128,128]".

Are you sure you want to be doing Concatenate along the batch dimension?  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, indeed batch_size is defaulted to 32. For sure I want an architecture that is able to deal with batch, and I thought that was the case due to the `None` in the Concatenate layer shapes. But the problem remain the same when initializing batch_size to None

Comment: Given the observation by @wohe1, and what I was suggesting, instead of setting axis=0 in the Concatenate function, which I believe is selecting the "batch dimension" you might want to consider axis=1, which is the channel dimension.  In Keras, you have to be a little careful, because the batch dimension tends to be treated automatically ("None"), so you don't usually need to think about it during building the layers, but in some functions you need to take care.  I hope this helps.